# Magento > Catalog Product List > Want to add orderBy with calcul

Tags: magento

I've this :

> $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()
>                       ->addAttributeToSort('special_price', 'desc');

I want to do something like :

> $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()
>                       ->addAttributeToSort('special_price*100/price', 'desc');

Actually the percentage of my promotion/sale is not saved in my database. But I want to orderby this percentage (with Mage Core or SQL). Can I do it that way or must I use php ?

I tried to custom the Select but it didn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may create additional column in your DB and name it 'my_special_price'.
But the better way is to use PHP.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to do it with Magento Query (using collection) ?

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly find my way to do it.

```
->addExpressionAttributeToSelect("pourcentage", "((100-({{special_price}}/price)*100))","special_price")
            ->addAttributeToSort("pourcentage","desc");
```

I don't need to sort the collection after the query !!